# How to upload image based on an array index using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to choose an image to be uploaded based on an array index, I've chosen to use an if statement. the problem I believe is inside the if statement itself and nothing wrong with my syntax. but correct me if I'm wrong.

I've tried using different syntaxes to append the new element that I'm creating inside a `div`:

```js
if (chosenWord === words[0]) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var src = document.getElementsByClassName("imgdivclass");
    img.src = "assets/images/lowtide.jpg";
}
```

The expected outcome is that I'm an able to create an image based upon a word that's chosen in my array. the word chose is random. just for your reference `chosenWord` variable is a randomly generated word within an array and `words` is my array.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new DOM node for the `<img>` but not appending it.

You need to decide where in the existing page DOM you want to add the image and then call [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

To just add the image element to the bottom of the current page use;

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);
```